# Derivative of function on $\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^m$

Tags: derivatives

If $f:\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^m \rightarrow \mathbb R$ then how we define derivative of $f$ at $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^m$?
I am assuming that we should consider $f$ as a function from $\mathbb R^{n+m}$ to $\mathbb R$ and use the definition of derivative of function $f:\mathbb R^{n+m}\rightarrow \mathbb R$. Am I right?

Comment: For future reference, enclose math in $, not `. Additionally, your idea sounds perfectly fine to me.

Comment: short answer: yes

Comment: Seems straightforward enough as you suggest.

Comment: In general, if we have $f:A \to B$, the derivative is a function
$Df:A \to L(A, B)$, where $L(A,B)$ is the collection of linear functions from $A$ to $B$.